# Fit All column on one page with EPPLUS c#

Tags: c#, epplus

I want to set printer setting Fit All column on one page with epplus. Can any on please help.

My code:

```
Worksheet.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;
Worksheet.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Landscape;
Worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;

Worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
```

Answer (score 24):

I think it's a bit counter intuitive but you also have to set `worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToHeight = 0` in order for this to work.

This is the code I usually use when setting up a worksheet for printing:

```
worksheet.PrinterSettings.PaperSize = ePaperSize.A4;
worksheet.PrinterSettings.Orientation = eOrientation.Portrait;
worksheet.PrinterSettings.HorizontalCentered = true;
worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToPage = true;
worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToWidth = 1;
worksheet.PrinterSettings.FitToHeight = 0;
```